# Add www on Elastic beanstalk & Route 53

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

At the moment I have web https://youhire.ie/ they are built by Rails 5 with AWS Elastic Beanstalk and it's working fine.

but one thing I like add https://www.youhire.ie/ and I have it add on route53, with alas on Elastic Beanstalk which the same method on https://youhire.ie/

[image]

so when i type 'www.youhire.ie'

You cannot visit www.youhire.ie right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work late

[image]

I am not sure what to do, I have look at the AWS document but can't find one.

so it would be great if I can add 'www' and redirect https://youhire.ie to https://www.youhire.ie

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `CNAME` record instead of an `A` record.  Create a `CNAME` record where the key is `www` and the value is the URL for the load balancer for your Elastic Beanstalk instance. You can find the URL by going to Elastic Beanstalk, and selecting your environment.  The URL is at the top of the page next to the Environment ID.

Comment: Have done it but it not working as i am using  "www.youhire.ie. CNAME awsuhirel2-env.cadycxsz98.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"

Comment: Is the issue that you are still getting the "Your connection is not private" error, or that it is not working at all? The "Your connection is not private" error means you don't have an SSL certificate applied to your load balancer on port 443 for your domain.